# theme.res not found on Codenameone IntellijIDEA IDE

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I am trying to create a Codenameone Application on IntelliJIDEA IDE. I have installed the codenameone plugin and created a CodeNameOne Application. When i run that application it gives an error **java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found**

Using:

IntelliJIDEA Version: **IntellijIDEA 2016.2.4**

JDK Version: **jdk1.8**

Here is the complete error log

```
Sep 19, 2016 10:44:21 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs  at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:736)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:700)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:664)
at com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager.initFirstTheme(UIManager.java:1534)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.init(MyApplication.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:81)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1151)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:968)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mycompany.myapp.MyApplication.start(MyApplication.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:106)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1151)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:968)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: This isn't the error, the project creation failed. I will need the full log from the project creation stage.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog i contacted the online chat support and they helped me out and now it's working. I gave the wrong Project SDK Location. 
Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was covered in the tracker https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1894